# Preencher banco expandindo um valor determinado em tantos itens

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho no banco o registro do prédio, com a quantidade de salas `qtdSala`, entre outros. Estou tentando inserir, em outro grid, cada sala de acordo com o valor entrado na `qtdSala`, pra registrar na tabela salas, através de um for, então tentei assim:

```
private void CriarSalas(int nSalas)
{
    for (int i = 0; 1 < nSalas; i++)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexaoString);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO salas
                     (nomeSala)
                VALUES
                     (@nomeSala)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeSala", i);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //Atualiza Grid
            this.salasTableAdapter.Fill(this.bdDataSet.salas);

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conexaoString);
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Não dá certo, não estou sabendo como referenciar o `nsalas`...

Ele deve pegar a `qtdsalas`, 20 por exemplo, e criar `sala01`, `sala02`...até `sala20`. Segue modelo da tabela:

```
TABELA SALAS
____________________________
| Id | IdPredio | NomeSala |
| 23 |       05 | "Sala01" |
| 24 |       05 | "Sala02" |
| 25 |       05 | "Sala03" |
| 26 |       05 | "Sala04" |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existem vários pontos a serem considerados, segue o código refatorado:

```
// tenha nomes de variaveis/parametros o mais claro possivel
private void CriarSalas(int idPredio, int quantidade) 
{
    try
    {
        // Cria a abre uma conexão no inicio do processo
        // Abrir e fechar conexão possui alto custo de processamento
        // Então abre-se no inicio do processo - loop - e encerra apenas no fim
        var con = new SqlConnection(conexaoString);
        con.Open();

        // para i igual a zero; enquanto i for menor que quantidade; incrementa +1
        for (int i = 0; i < quantidade; i++)
        {
            // Reduza a quantidade de tráfego entre sua aplicação e o banco de dados.
            // Lembre-se, cada caracter possui pelo menos 16-bits de tamanho ou 2-bytes.
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                @"INSERT INTO salas(idPredio, nomeSala)VALUES(@idPredio,@nomeSala)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPredio", idPredio);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeSala", $"Sala0{i}");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Se houver error, exibe a mensagem do erro
        MessageBox.Show($"Erro ao tentar criar sala: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        // Isso deveria ser feito em outro método.
        // Cada método, classe, deve ter responsabilidade unica
        // Esse método deve apenas criar salas, crie outro para atualizar o grid. 
        // Atualiza Grid, porém isso deveria ser feito em outro método.
        //this.salasTableAdapter.Fill(this.bdDataSet.salas);

        // Ao terminar, encerra a conexão    
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: beleza, gostei das dicas de boas práticas, vou seguir. Mas ainda tenho uma dúvida: qdo eu falo que a quantidade vai ser o valor de qtdSalas? faço um where no insert e depois defino a quantidade = qtdSalas.value? ou só mando quantidade receber qtd salas?

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta adicionando como é a estrutura da tabela salas. Pois não entendi sua dúvida.

Comment: oi, desculpe a demora, estava dando uma organizada no código. A tabela salas vai receber o os predios, onde tem a qtdSalas, então na tabelas salas vai aparecer o nome do predio e sala01, sala02....só que as salas devem ser listadas numa única coluna, isso que eu não sei fazer, no mesmo idPredio terá tantas salas quantas estiverem na quantidade qtdSalas. Consegui esclarecer? eu acho que eu tenho que relacionar a quantidade com o qtdSalas mas não sei como....

Comment: Editei minha resposta, veja se agora atende.

Comment: Alterei também os comentários do código. :)

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nomeSala", $"Sala0{i}"); acho que é isso, isso que eu não sabia escrever, vou testar e te falo. Obrigado.

Comment: Se funcionar, por favor, avalie a resposta! :)

Comment: cara, que trabalhera que me deu fazer isso funcionar....mas a sua resposta foi o que ajudou!! Muito Obrigado.